# SQL Query with Joins repeats the Data of Topmost row for all other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

The following SQL query retrieves and repeats the data of the top most row for all the other rows.

```
SELECT 
    Student.StuRollNo, Student.StuName, Student.StuFName, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 M.SubjectObtMarks 
     FROM Marking M 
     WHERE M.SubjectID = 'SubUrdu' 
       AND M.ExamID = 1) AS Urdu,
    (SELECT TOP 1 M.SubjectObtMarks 
     FROM Marking M 
     WHERE M.SubjectID = 'SubEng' 
       AND M.ExamID = 1) AS Eng,
    (SELECT TOP 1 M.SubjectObtMarks 
     FROM Marking M 
     WHERE M.SubjectID = 'SubPhy' 
       AND M.ExamID = 1) AS Phy,
    (SELECT TOP 1 M.SubjectObtMarks 
     FROM Marking M 
     WHERE M.SubjectID = 'SubChem' 
       AND M.ExamID = 1) AS Chem,
    (SELECT TOP 1 M.SubjectObtMarks 
     FROM Marking M 
     WHERE M.SubjectID = 'SubBio' 
       AND M.ExamID = 1) AS Bio,
    (SELECT TOP 1 M.SubjectObtMarks 
     FROM Marking M 
     WHERE M.SubjectID = 'SubIsl' 
       AND M.ExamID = 1) AS Isl,
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(Marking.SubjectObtMarks) 
     FROM Marking 
     WHERE ExamID = 1) AS ObtMarks
FROM 
    Exam, Student 
INNER JOIN 
    PrimaryData ON Student.StuRollNo = PrimaryData.StuID 
INNER JOIN 
    Section ON Section.SectionID = PrimaryData.SectionID 
WHERE 
    Section.SectionName = 'M1' 
    AND Exam.ExamID = 1;
```

Here's what it retrieves:

[image: Problem Pic]

Database diagram:

[image: DB Diagram]

Please help me resolve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, standard, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you do not restrict which Student the Marking belongs to anywhere. 
So your query is essentially always picking up the first Marking, and not checking who this Marking belongs to.

```
SELECT 
Student.StuRollNo, Student.StuName, Student.StuFName, 
(SELECT TOP 1 M.SubjectObtMarks 
 FROM Marking M 
 WHERE M.SubjectID = 'SubUrdu' 
   AND M.ExamID = 1
   AND M.StuID = S.StuID) AS Urdu
FROM 
    Exam, Student S
INNER JOIN 
    PrimaryData ON Student.StuRollNo = PrimaryData.StuID 
INNER JOIN 
    Section ON Section.SectionID = PrimaryData.SectionID
```

Comment: Query Executed with these Errors: ` Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
The multi-part identifier "Student.StuRollNo" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "Student.StuRollNo" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "Student.StuName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "Student.StuFName" could not be bound.`